# How to close a window when user clicks on mainwindow in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application which shows a window as a DialogBox.
I want to close this DialogBox when I click anywhere on MainWindow in application.

Here I am adding one sample example to explain

MainWindow of application

```html
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Open new Window" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind main Window

```js
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window1 temp_Window = new Window1();
            temp_Window.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Child window Which I try to close

```html
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" Deactivated="Window_Deactivated">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>New Window</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind This Child Window

```js
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @SamTheDev I try to close window(Which I open using DialogBox in application) when click on anywhere on mainwindow of application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with Deactivated event of your DialogBox window

something like this

> XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="200" Width="200" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        Deactivated="Window_Deactivated">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

> Code

```
private void Window_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: It close window when I click outside of application and not on main window of application.

Comment: when you click on mainwindow then it is outside of DialogBox window

Comment: Yes when i click on mainwindow it is outside of dialogbox but it close dialogbox only when i click outside of whole application

Comment: ohhh i got it you need to open dialogbox with show() methos instead of showdialog() method

Answer (score 0):

If you call the DialogBox with ShowDialog the background window (which is the MainWindow) will be disabled until you close the DialogBox and it won't get any click, so there is no way for you to achieve what you want unless you call the DialogBox with Show method which won't lock the background window, then you can close the DialogBox whenever MainWindow GotFocus fires.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your second window as a global variable and call the .Hide() and .Show() commands like that:

MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    private Dialog m_Dialog;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_Dialog = new Dialog();
        this.Click += closeDialog;
    }

    private void closeDialog(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_Dialog.Hide();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_Dialog.Show();
    }
}
```

It works just fine.

**UPDATED**:

Here is the same code for WPF. I did it in WinForms previously:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Dialog m_Dialog;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_Dialog = new Dialog();
        this.MouseDoubleClick += onCloseDialog;
    }

    private void onCloseDialog(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        m_Dialog.Hide();
    }

    private void onButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_Dialog.Show();
    }
}
```

You can use another event instead of MouseDoubleClick of course.
If you really want to **close** the window you would have to use the .Close() command and call the constructor of you window everytime.

Answer (score 0):

first declare your `temp_window` as a filed not as a local variable:

```
private Window1 temp_Window;
```

When you open the new window don't open it as a dialog otherwise, the events on the mainWindow will not be handled use `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()` :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            temp_Window = new Window1();
            temp_Window.Show();
        }
```

On your main window handle the `mouseDown` event:

```
MouseDown="MainWindow_OnMouseDown"
```

and close the `tempWindow` in the handler

```
 private void MainWindow_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        tempWindow .Close();
    }
```